# How to add scope option in adminside magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, store-view, scope

How to add website scope option in my custom module to the admin side

programmatically if any idea or suggestion link please let me know to

do this functionality.like this see the below snap.

[image]

Comment: please explain bit more

Comment: Okay, sure I used this functionality in the tax rule for a specific website like.
There is a Magento limitation to display a common tax rule-setting for all stores. 
We required to set up a specific tax rule for a specific website.
So that I used this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **In Ui-Component From Field**

```
    <field name="storeviews">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">storeviews</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">storeviews</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Comment: Thank you Msquare,
Can I know how to use this scope in Magento tax rule admin panel section,
And where can add this XML code?
Please explain this file structure.